# Capybara- how to test link to different section of same page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In my Rails app, I have the following links at the top of a page:

```
<ul>
  <li><%= link_to 'Group Chairperson', '#group_chair' %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Group Treasurer', '#group_treasurer' %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Group Secretary', '#group_secretary' %></li>
</ul>
```

Farther down the page, I have the following table row selector:

```
<tr id="group_chair">
```

A click on the 'Group Chairperson' link causes the browser to scroll down to the correct table row as expected.  Now I want to make a spec which tests this feature.  I tried the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Group officer duties page" do

  before { visit group_officer_duties_path }

  it "should scroll down to the right section" do
    click_link "Group Chairperson"
    expect(current_url).to eq "http://www.example.com/group_officer_duties#group_chair"
  end

end
```

I would expect this test to pass, since this is what the URL bar of my browser shows after a click on the right link.  However, I actually get this:

```
Failures:

  1) Group officer duties page should scroll down to the right section
     Failure/Error: expect(current_url).to eq "http://www.example.com/group_officer_duties#group_chair"

       expected: "http://www.example.com/group_officer_duties#group_chair"
            got: "http://www.example.com/group_officer_duties"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/requests/group_officer_duties_nav_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.94885 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Any idea what's up with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe you are out of luck - the following answer comes from Jonas Nicklas himself:

> the anchor is never submitted to the server, so from that point
>     of view, it kind of makes sense for current_url to not include the
>     Anchor. There's very little we can about that behaviour from inside
>     Capybara, I'm afraid. MY guess is that the issue goes as far down as
>     HTMLUnit.
>
> That being said, I personally never assert anything on the URL anyway,
>     I find that it's bad practice in integration tests. That's just my
>     oppinion though.
>
> /Jonas

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/KMEWM8nuZlE

Comment: So if asserting against the URL is bad practice, is the better practice to assert against the path?  Or does this case call for something like Selenium instead?

Comment: I think, what he actually means is, that this is something, that you shouldn't test in a high-level-integration test. Instead, you should check it in your view, like shown [here](https://gist.github.com/them0nk/2166525) (even though I don't consider that best pracitce either)